# How can I reload my main form after changing UICulture without losing my controls state

Tags: vb.net, winforms, uiculture

I'm doing a program that controls motors and the user can change the language of the application. I need to reload my form to update some labels and buttons names, but all states are lost. How can I reload it without losing my controls states?

I have this code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
Me.Controls.Clear() 'removes all the controls on the form
initialize_component() 'load all the controls again
Main_Form_Load(e, e)
```

Doing this I lose the state.

Comment: [Application.Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.restart) -- [Manage Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Did you tried without removing controls?

Comment: If I don't remove the controls and then load them again the language don't change. I think the only way is when the user change the language, I change the name of the labels one by one.

Comment: I can see two options: 1. Extract applying labels values into separate method and call it after changing thread language.  2. Save current values into an object and apply them to "new" controls after changing the language.  
I would suggest to go with first approach, because it is exactly what you wanna do.

Comment: Your controls should be presenting (not storing) application state; if they are just presenting application state, then reloading will not lose anything, because as you reload, you will rebuild the form presentation from the application state.  (By "should" I mean "this is the right way to do things, and if you don't do it this way, you'll run into trouble in the future, like when you want to reload it without losing your controls states".)

Comment: So @Craig what are you saying is that I should save all of my states for example in settings and when I reload the form I get the states?

Comment: It depends on what the states mean.  If they mean application settings, then the the application state would be saved to settings.  If they mean application data, then presumably there is a backing database or a file you can save to.

Comment: Thanks guys for help!